# Deleting a GroupBox with MouseClick event in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I am programmatically creating GroupBoxes which include delete buttons inside them. I want to delete the GroupBoxes when these buttons are clicked, via the `btnSil_Click` event.

Here is the code I have so far in `form_load`:

```
for (i=0;i<AnaEkranForm.n1;i++)
{
    GroupBox gBKisaMetin = new GroupBox();
    this.Controls.Add(gBKisaMetin);
    gBKisaMetin.Location = new Point(80, gYuksek);
    gYuksek += 200;
    gBKisaMetin.Text = "Soru " + (soruSayac++);
    gBKisaMetin.Width=500;

    gBKisaMetin.Height = 150;

    TextBox tBSoru = new TextBox();
    tBSoru.Location = new Point(30, 30);
    tBSoru.Width = 400;
    gBKisaMetin.Controls.Add(tBSoru);

    Label labelCevap = new Label();
    labelCevap.Location = new Point(30, 70);
    labelCevap.Text = "Cevap";
    gBKisaMetin.Controls.Add(labelCevap);

    TextBox tBKisaMetinCevap = new TextBox();
    tBKisaMetinCevap.Location = new Point(30, 95);
    tBKisaMetinCevap.Width = 400;

    gBKisaMetin.Controls.Add(tBKisaMetinCevap);
    tBKisaMetinCevap.ReadOnly = true;

    Button btnSil = new Button();
    btnSil.Location = new Point(460, 10);
    btnSil.Width = 30;
    btnSil.Text = "Sil";
    btnSil.Name = "btnSil_" + i.ToString();
    btnSil.Click += new EventHandler(btnSil_Click);

    gBKisaMetin.Controls.Add(btnSil);
}
```

`AnaEkranForm.n1` is the number of GroupBoxes which will be created.

And here is my button click handler for deleting:

```
private void btnSil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(gBKisaMetin);
    gBKisaMetin.Dispose();
}
```

But this isn't working because I can't access `gBkisaMetin`. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please add more information to the question by editing. What are you having problems with? Is something not working? Please add a question for others to answer.

Comment: You right.I edit the question

Comment: The code you have posted isn't complete and so it is hard to understand, especially with the foreign language variable names. It may be best if you post a more complete example of the code you currently have, and what you have tried so far to get it do what you want.

Comment: private void btnSil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(gBKisaMetin);
            gBKisaMetin.Dispose();
        }

Comment: @CanerÜnver preferably in your question body.

Comment: `gBKisaMetin` will not be available in the click handler because it is a local variable in your `Form1_Load`. Does each GroupBox have an associated delete button?

Comment: @CallumWatkins yes each groupbox have association an delete buttons

Answer (score 0):

So since the GroupBox is the parent of the delete Button, you should be able to access it very simply like this:

```
private void btnSil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control groupBox = ((Button)sender).Parent;
    this.Controls.Remove(groupBox);
    groupBox.Dispose();
}
```

This casts the sender to a Button, then accesses the parent control (the GroupBox) via the [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) property. The GroupBox can then be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

You could also store a reference to the GroupBox in the `Tag` property of your Button when you create it:

```
Button btnSil = new Button();
btnSil.Tag = gBKisaMetin;
```

Now you can retrieve that reference in the click handler:

```
private void btnSil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GroupBox gb = (GroupBox)btn.Tag;
    gb.Dispose(); // will automatically remove it as well
}
```

This approach differs in that the Button does not need to be inside the GroupBox for this to work.